# Can anyone tell me the value of this resistor

Tags: resistors

I put the colors into fields on a webpage but when I get to the 3rd color reading it in both directions the color is not there????????????????

No larger space between bands so I know I'm reading it in the correct direction....

Here is the pic-[image]

Comment: What do you read the colours as?

Comment: Why can't you measure its value?

Comment: From left to right, brown, pink, white, gray, red. I know pink is not a color used. They should just print the resistance, ie 37.2K  fried resistors colors probably change the same you just need to have a chart for what the fried colors change to.

Comment: I have the same problem and I can see the resistor in bad shape but I don't know what capacitor is the bad one can you please tell me or if you have a picture show me the one thank you

Answer (score 3):

That resistor is heavily overheated. Coulors turned out to something totally impredictable.

Nobody can guess its value.

Unless it is still functional and can be measured (don't think so), or you've got schematics you can only try to reverse engineer that area and put something which sounds appropriate.

Most likely this has been caused by some other fault around, do not forget to spot and solve it before trying with a new one.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the second band from the left is pink, which is most likely an error since that isn't a standard color.  It probably should be red.

Reading it from Right to Left, we have Red, Grey, White, Red, Brown.  This is equal to (289)*10^2 = 28.9K with a 1% tolerance.

Comment: [Really](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_number#E_series)?

Answer (score 0):

Went to the local electronics supply store, Greenbrook Electronics, not many around like it anymore. Gave the resistor and capacitor to the guy behind the counter and he matched up a 30K ohm resistor he didnt have the 28.7K Ohm and a 220Uf 50V capacitor for a total of $2.95. Went home and soldered them in and the microwave works fine now, no buzzing. Hopefully good for another 14 years.....LOL  Thanks for everyone's input!

Comment: You can accept your own answer - if you think it's correct!